# How to notify XAML properties when list data of binding changed?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding

I'm using the following code for binding

XAML

```
<StackPanel x:Name="channelsRecordTimeData" Orientation="Vertical">
    <ItemsControl x:Name="channelRecordTimeItems" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate> 
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid x:Name="gridChannelRecordTimeItem" Width="{Binding Path=ChannelRecordTimeItemWidth}"                                                                                                                
                      Height="{Binding Path=ChannelRecordTimeItemHeight}" Margin="{Binding Path=ChannelRecordTimeItemsMargin}"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Left" DataContext="{Binding Path=ListRecordTime}">
                    <Grid.Background>
                        <ImageBrush x:Name="gridChannelRecordTimeItemBgr" ImageSource="..\Resources\playback_grid_channel_record_time_item_bgr_normal.png"/>
                    </Grid.Background>                                    
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</StackPanel>
```

C#

```
public class DATA
{
    public double ChannelRecordTimeItemWidth { set; get; }
    public double ChannelRecordTimeItemHeight { set; get; }
    public Thickness ChannelRecordTimeItemsMargin { set; get; }
    public List<RecordTime> ListRecordTime { set; get; }

    public DATA()
    {
        ChannelRecordTimeItemWidth = 1000;
        ChannelRecordTimeItemHeight = 20;
        ChannelRecordTimeItemsMargin = new System.Windows.Thickness(0, 0, 0, 0);
        ListRecordTime = null;
    }
}

public static List<DATA> listDATA = new List<DATA>();
for(int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++)
{
    DATA data = new DATA();
    listDATA.Add(data);
}
channelRecordTimeItems.ItemsSource = listDATA;
channelRecordTimeItems.Items.Refresh();
```

This code will notify to the XAML update when I use the line of code as

```
listDATA[0].ChannelRecordTimeItemWidth -= 15;
```

There is any way to XAML update properties automatically, when we manipulate on the listDATA as

```
listDATA.RemoveAt();
listDATA.Add();
listDATA.Clear();
```

Without calling the two following lines code

```
channelRecordTimeItems.ItemsSource = listDATA;
channelRecordTimeItems.Items.Refresh();
```

Answer (score 1):

GUI will be updated only in case `underlying source collection is implementing INotifyCollectionChanged` which raise `CollectionChanged` events to refresh GUI components.

You can use [ObservableCollection](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) which internally provides you this feature.

Replace

```
public static List<DATA> listDATA = new List<DATA>();
```

with

```
public static ObservableCollection<DATA> listDATA = new ObservableCollection<DATA>();
```

Comment: You need to replace `List<T>` with `ObservableCollection<T>` only. Rest will work as it is.

Comment: Also you can refer to example at last [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms668604%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Thank you!I have read it, but I don't know how to solve my problem. That is the GUI will update automatically when I call listDATA.RemoveAt();
listDATA.Add();
listDATA.Clear();

Comment: If this collection is binded to your GUI then you don't have to worry about updating GUI. Any modification in list will automatically update your GUI. Have you tried it?